# Xcode 5: keyboard shortcut for 'Edit Breakpoint'?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints, xcode5

I know that one can <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-click to open the `Edit Breakpoint...` window, but that is hardly better than right-click. **Is there (or, can one make) a keyboard shortcut for this action?**
[image]